# how can i use capslock function on a virtual keyboard using javascript if the textarea that handles the string value is readOnly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have used this code but it only detects if the capslock is on or off.

```
$(function () {
        var isShiftPressed = false;
        var isCapsOn = null;
        $("#txtName").bind("keydown", function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (keyCode == 16) {
                isShiftPressed = true;
            }
        });
        $("#txtName").bind("keyup", function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (keyCode == 16) {
                isShiftPressed = false;
            }
            if (keyCode == 20) {
                if (isCapsOn == true) {
                    isCapsOn = false;


                    $("#error").hide();
                } else if (isCapsOn == false) {
                    isCapsOn = true;
                    $("#error").show(); 
                }
            }
        });
        $("#txtName").bind("keypress", function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90 && !isShiftPressed) {
                isCapsOn = true;
                $("#error").show();
            } else {
                $("#error").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

but this is not functioning if the textarea that hold the value is in readOnly state.
how can i fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Of course the code doesn't work on a readonly field, because the keypress, keydown events are not fired.

Comment: How can you do what?

Comment: i used event.keycode to have an output in the textarea even it is in readonly but its all in lower case what i wanted to do is when i on the capslock the value of what i have press would be on capslock like the normal keyboard

Comment: document.onkeydown = function(){
   document.getElementById("txtInput").focus();
    if (event.keyCode == "65"){
       document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="a";
       btnA.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
      }
      if (event.keyCode == "66"){
       document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="b";
       btnB.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
      } }

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your English; still not sure what your question is.    What is the ID of this textarea you keep talking about?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
$("#txtName")
```

with

```
$('body')
```

Comment: This is an answer to what I assume your question is.

Comment: still there is no input on the textarea because it is on readOnly state

Comment: So make it not readonly?  That's what readonly means:  READ ONLY:  not writeable.  You haven't even told us which control is the textarea...

Comment: I suspect you are not even showing us the code you're asking a question about.  You seem to be asking why the output that should be in a textarea is not showing when that textarea is readonly.  You need to show us the code that tries to set the value of that textarea.

Comment: See my other answer for another guess about what your question might be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use onkeypress instead of onkeydown.  The latter only detects which key was pressed; the former (even though counter-intuitively its name includes 'keypress') will give you the char.  This link explains in detail:  http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html  Note that onkeypress is not supported by all browsers.

Also, your code for converting charcode to char is inefficient, and you're converting uppercase charcodes to lowercase chars.  Here's some code that listens for key presses and on each one, alerts the user which char was pressed.

```
    document.onkeypress = function(event){
        event = event || window.event; 
        var key = event.keyCode;
        alert(String.fromCharCode(key));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (event.keyCode == "65"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+=val1;
                        btnA.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "66"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="b";
                        btnB.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "67"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="c";
                        btnC.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "68"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="d";
                        btnD.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "69"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="e";
                        btnE.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "70"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="f";
                        btnF.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "71"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="g";
                        btnG.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "72"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="h";
                        btnH.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "73"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="i";
                        btnI.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "74"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="j";
                        btnJ.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "75"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="k";
                        btnK.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "76"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="l";
                        btnL.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "77"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="m";
                        btnM.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "78"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="n";
                        btnN.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "79"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="o";
                        btnO.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "80"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="p";
                        btnP.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "81"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="q";
                        btnQ.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "82"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="r";
                        btnR.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "83"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="s";
                        btnS.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "84"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="t";
                        btnT.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "85"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="u";
                        btnU.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "86"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="v";
                        btnV.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "87"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="w";
                        btnW.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "88"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="x";
                        btnX.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "89"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="y";
                        btnY.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
                    if (event.keyCode == "90"){
                        document.getElementById("txtInput").value+="z";
                        btnZ.style.backgroundColor="#00bfff";
                    }
```

thats the code i used so when i press a-z in the keyboard it will have a-z in the textarea. But even if the capslock is ON its still on lowercase.

Comment: Yeah, that's because you haven't added the proper character codes.  See my third answer.

Comment: Also, I don' t know where you got the above code but it seems incredibly bad. You have 26 if blocks which are not needed.  You could use functions such as charCodeAt and/or fromCharCode instead.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, maybe I was being a little harsh.  The point is that there are better ways to do it.  I didn't think you had written it yourself... if that's the case I'm surprised you didn't already know you were using the uppercase codes.

Comment: Can you alterate my code that not using too many if statement if you dont mind...thanks..:)

Comment: You should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: However, see the answer I just added.